# Ubuntu 20.04: Can't find basic application menu on the dock and appearance menu in settings

Tags: upgrade, settings, appmenu, appearance, 20.04

Application menu which is usually found on the leftmost bottom containing all the system and installed applications is missing after the update.

The theme is by default set to bright white one and appearance setting is no where found in Setting menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolved!!

During login, I selected Ubuntu from the options available; initially it was gnome.