# Appearance option missing in Gnome Control Center

Tags: gnome, 20.04, gnome-control-center

Currently I am running Ubuntu 20.04 and I have an issue with the Gnome Control Center, which is the last version `3.36.1` and does not show the `Appearance` option in the settings list.
I have tried reinstalling it, but I still can't see the option. Anyone else facing the same issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I just noticed now I have the same problem I was search for an answer online.

Comment: Same here, I upgrade my ubuntu 18 to 20 and didn't get the appearance option

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem, this solved it: https://askubuntu.com/a/1230698
Basically I was logging in using "Gnome on Xorg" rather than "Ubuntu"

Comment: This solved my problem . I was logging in using "Gnome on Xong" too. Thank you!

Comment: Doesn't help my case.I still have this problem...

Comment: i login to a remote linux server (ubuntu 20) this seems to be the case for me too. How do i know which way i have logged in ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but after logging "Ubuntu" won't appear in the login. The only way I found was to reinstall ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

It worked perfectly: after reinstallation, "Ubuntu" appeared in the login and the problem, I selected it and everything was restored

Comment: will this work for a remote server ?