# How can I pin the Ubuntu dock?

Tags: 20.04, dock

How can I make the Ubuntu dock (side bar) to not disappear when the mouse is not hovered in case the **Appearance** section is missing from settings?

OS: Ubuntu 20.04

[image: Ubuntu Dock]

[image: Settings]

Thanks.

Comment: @user68186 no it didn't unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @user68186 actually it did, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231991/appearance-option-missing-in-gnome-control-center) w/ regard to the missing appearance option.

Also you might be able to use dconf-editor to allow customisation of the desktop appearance/behaviour.

```
sudo apt install dconf-editor
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it didn't help.

Comment: Actually it helped me, just needed to log in using "Ubuntu" instead of "Gnome on Xorg", thanks!