# I deleted something I shouldn't have

Tags: command-line, themes, repository, 21.04

So, I was deleting 'PPA's' that i didn't need anymore, most of theme being ones that didn't work while I was downloading themes. and I miss clicked and deleted one that had a check mark next to it. (I assume this mean that it was enabled in working, correct me if I'm wrong I'm fairly new to this still). TLDR now there are some obvious things that are not working or have disappeared. The most obvious (so far) are that "appearance" has disappeared from settings. and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> isn't doing anything anymore. I'm sure there is more and i just haven't noticed yet. if anyone knows a fix to these issues it would be greatly appreciated, I've done some looking but so far I've been empty handed.

Also I'm on 21.04 I probably should've said that earlier.

Comment: It sounds to me like you were in *Software and Updates* and in the *Other Software* tab (https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/addremove-ppa.html.en) where PPAs are added/removed... You don't add/remove packages there, only sources, so adding/removing a PPA won't cause changes to your desktop.  However if you're talking about something else, more specific details may help us understand. Ctrl+Alt+T for example may stop working if you removed the `python` package, not a 3rd party repository (ie. PPA)

Comment: The way to restore is the following - switch to text console by <Ctrl>+<Alt>+<F3>, login to it, then reinstall at least gnome-terminal by `sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-terminal` . Then reboot.

Comment: you are right on where i was, i clicked remove on the wrong ppa, and then this stuff started to happen. how would one get the python package back?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps you: [Ubuntu 20.04: Can't find basic application menu on the dock and appearance menu in settings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1229951/ubuntu-20-04-cant-find-basic-application-menu-on-the-dock-and-appearance-menu/1230698#1230698)

Try googling you symptoms. This often is more helpful than asking the question, or at least a quicker way to the solution.

In the ppas you actually can't remove any packages. And did you know which ppas exactly you removed? Normally, you can just uncheck them and they will be ignored during updates/upgrades.